# Average operation by capacitor

Tags: capacitor

How can capacitor perform the  average of a signal given as input? Like we do in case of RMS to DC conversion.

Comment: Low pass filter, lookup pwm dac as example

Comment: True RMS to DC is not possible with a simple LPF or other simple capacitor circuit.

Comment: yes, squarer and averaging and squareroot ckty will b reqd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the defining equation of a capacitor, the current through a capacitor is equal to the integral of the voltage across it. Since an integral amounts to averaging, in principle you can get the average of a signal by applying it across a capacitor and then measuring the current through the capacitor. For RMS to DC conversion you need to perform 3 operations: squaring (S), averaging or mean (M), and square root (R).  The capacitor can only be used to do the averaging part, the rest requires more circuitry.